# Customer JSF Exception Handler does not catch Exception in Converter

Tags: jsf, converters, exceptionhandler

I have an own ExceptionHandler added to my jsf 2.2 project.
web.xml

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>package.exceptionhandler.MyExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

The exceptionHandlerFactory contains

```
public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
    ExceptionHandler handler = new MyExceptionHandler(parent.getExceptionHandler());
    return handler;
}
```

and the ExceptionHandler contains

```
 @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {
        LOGGER.debug("handle exception...");
    }
```

My dummy Converter throw everytime an exception:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "MyConverter")
public class MyConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent comp, final String value) {
    throw new RuntimeException("error");
}
//...
```

But the exception is not handled by my own excpetion handler. Why?

Comment: "I have an own ExceptionHandler added to my jsf 2.2 project. web.xml" did you mean faces-config.xml? Because this is where it has to be.

Comment: Are you implying that the handler *is* invoked when the exception is thrown elsewhere, e.g. in action method?

Comment: hi Noone, you are right. it was of course the faces-config.xml. It was a typo in my question. The root cause of the problem was a phaselistener (see answere below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.

That was not an issue from jsf. I had a PhaseListener in the application, which makes only some of the error messages visible on the page. But this PhaseListener was in the INVOKE_APPLICATION Phase and therefore never executed.